# Is there a Japanese phrase equivalent to "crisis of faith"

Tags: meaning, phrase-requests

I am wondering if there is a way to describe this concept in Japanese, or an equivalent phrase.

According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crisis_of_faith it is a mostly western concept (if you believe wikipedia anyway).

I am asking in relation to the definition in the first paragraph, not in the religious sense.

This phrase relates to “deciding whether to make (or being forced to make) a choice that goes against ones most basic beliefs.

And in the process, either retain that belief, or drop it in favor of another one. It is this situation that causes the internal conflict.

I do not believe it is directly related to simple inability to make a decision, not knowing what to believe, nor the process of self-discovery in general.”

Comment: It might be helpful to explain a bit more in detail what you are looking for. A native speaker might be able to give you the closest phrase/idea, but if they don't know what you're really looking for to begin with...

Comment: I found examples of 信仰の危機, but I think that translation implies a crisis of *religious* faith...

Comment: What about `信念の危機`?

Comment: I believe Japanese people are more interdependant than say Americans that tend to be very independent. Japanese people 
are also much more conscious of how they are viewed/perceived by others. So in my opinion it is more likely that someone would do/act as expected, even if they strongly believe it is wrong. The crisis is the moment when they have to decide one way or another. Its this situation that I am trying to find a definition for.

Comment: 信条の危機？？？.......

Comment: Depending on the context, maybe you could say something like `何を信じればいいのか迷っている` "I'm not sure what I should believe (in)" (?)

Comment: @Chocolate - Thanks. I am afraid the term 信条 is too conceptual for my japanese skill level, but I looked it up on ALC and I think its pretty close. But I wonder if there is an actual phrase as in English. Then I could use this to web search for more information on how the concept applies in Japan. 信仰の危機 seems to be religious as snailplane mentioned, but google searches on the other two got no hits.

Comment: う～ん、やっぱり信条の危機はおかしいですね・・ヒットもほとんどないです。

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate all of your suggestions. Still it seems to me to be a difference between “being unsure or unable to move forward” or “not being able to make a decision or decide what to believe” versus “deciding whether to make a choice that goes against your most basic beliefs”. The latter is the situation I am asking about. I think 信条 describes the belief OK, but it doesn't describe the conflict itself. I think 自分探し refers more to the overall journey rather than the moment of crisis. I'll add some more detail to the question.

Comment: I could be wrong, but regarding your edit I think it's likely there isn't something which directly translates to what you're looking for. Could you use a phrase with ["internal conflict"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_conflict) in it's place? Space ALC has a number of examples, including [心の葛藤](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E5%BF%83%E3%81%AE%E8%91%9B%E8%97%A4) and [精神的葛藤](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E7%B2%BE%E7%A5%9E%E7%9A%84%E8%91%9B%E8%97%A4) etc (I think some sort of phrase with [葛藤](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E8%91%9B%E8%97%A4) might be close though)

Answer (score 4):

There are a few phrases that are commonly used.

- 「分からなくなってきた」（e.g.　何を信じればいいのか分からなくなってきた、自分の気持ちが
  分からなくなってきた、あなたのことが分からなくなってきた）
- 「自分探し」　(e.g.　やりたい事が見つからないので、自分探しにいってきます）

You could also use 葛藤、e.g.「自分がやってきたことが正しかったのか、すごく葛藤した時期」、「どちらの道に進むべきか分からず、葛藤し続けた」

Comment: じゃあ。。「迷い」みたいな感じかな・・

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the context, you might also be able to use  疑心暗鬼（ぎしんあんき）, meaning doubt begets doubt, which is commonly used to express a sort of negative momentum in one's thinking.